# Calculate index values instead of absolute values in d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

How can I calculate the index value (`x[i] / x[0] * 100`) of an array (timeseries) in pure javascript and in d3?

In pure javascript I can create a new a array and push the calculated values into this, but it seems quite time consuming. Is it possible to do this in a smart way?

I actually need my d3 graph to use index values rather than absolute values.

## Edit

I have an array of objects

```
[
  { date: '1/3/2016', value: 10 },
  { date: '2/3/2016', value: 13 },
  { date: '3/3/2016', value: 17 },
  ..
]
```

After calculating the index values, I want the array

```
[
  { date: '1/3/2016', value: 100 },
  { date: '2/3/2016', value: 130 },
  { date: '2/3/2016', value: 170 },
  ..
]
```

whose values are calculated as `y_i / y_0 * 100` where `y_0` is the base value.

I need it in my d3 chart which is an exact copy of https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/02d893e3486c70c4475f, so doing it directly in d3 would be great.

A problem is that I cannot be entirely sure if the array is sorted by date, so maybe I have to sort it beforehand.

Comment: It seems that you just need to access your array with the second argument in the anonymous function... Can you clarify your question? Maybe providing an example of what you want?

Comment: Well, now it seems to me that this is just a matter of iterating the array.